# ENOENT error while deploy JEST test with THREE JS OrbitControls

Tags: angular, jestjs, three.js, enoent, orbitcontrols

I´ve finished the implementations of a new feature that uses Orbit Controls library, they all work properly, the three Js module is imported as documentation says:

*import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';*

but later when I relaunch the JEST test that worked before it throws the error:

ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\d.mauricio\Documents\development\cadm-ui-cad-editor\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\controls\OrbitControls'

```
   7 | import { Point } from 'src/app/models/GeometryObject/point';
   8 | import { Segment } from 'src/app/models/GeometryObject/segment';
>  9 | import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
     | ^
```

The file is at the correct route as i've checked, and also it compiles and works, so I dont understand why it throws this error while testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without reproducible code, it's a bit difficult to find **exact** reason what's causing this issue. There are several ways to handle this issues:

## 1. Make Jest bundler runs in same environment

Whether the app compiles or not should not matter because Jest runs in different compilation environment. The project needs to provide a separate module bundler setting, that's synced with the project's bundler setting.

- make sure `jest.config.js` has matching module resolution setting as the project's bundler setting. check [this official document](https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack) on `jest.config.js`
- make sure `OrbitControls.js` is not excluded from Jest bundler setting.
- in some cases, if the project is based on toolchains that provides automatic Jest configuration, i.g. Next.js, Nuxt.js..., it might not be necessary.

## 2. Make OrbitControls run in your folder

- the problem arises because `OrbitControls.js` is not a compiled source, unlike most files provided from `node_modules`. It's a just an example of camera implementation. Thus, it confuses compiler/bundler.
- `OrbitControls.js` itself is actually quite simple, the implementation does not bring any dependencies. [check OrbitControls.js source code on Github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js).
- just copy `OrbitControls.js` from that folder,  paste in your folder, and import from there. It'll probably work in most cases.

Comment: the first solution did not work. The second solution I am curious what happens if they update the addon for OrbitControls? if we make a copy then we no longer are aware of changes to such file. Unless we manually check.

Comment: @adarian as the path/folder name suggests(example), `OrbitControls` is a bare minimum implementation of orbit-ish control. It is not really suitable for any serious production-grade camera control. That's why it has awkward compatibility with `import`. I always end up using other more elaborate camera controlling libraries or extend the example by myself in most cases. Believe me, relying on `OrbitControls` would turn out to be not such a great idea in the near future: it lacks many details such as smooth animation, camera lock etc.